# MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I am trying to pass a List of objects as a parameter between different instances of the same viewmodel (recursive) using `ShowViewModel<ViewModel, Type>(parameter)`.
I am having this error in my MVVMCross/xamarin forms project.

```
 MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and 
initialize ViewModel for type Project.Core.ViewModels.ObjectViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Problem creating viewModel of type ObjectViewModel ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter obj of type ObjectItem when creating Project.Core.ViewModels.ObjectViewModel
  at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x00036] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\IoC\MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs:502 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x0002c] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\IoC\MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs:312 
  at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00006] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\Mvx.cs:169 
  at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000] in C:\projects\mvvmcross\MvvmCross\Core\Core\ViewModels\MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.cs:33
```

to explain more, here is my code:

**ObjectPage.xaml**

```
<mvx:MvxContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:mvx="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Core;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
         x:Class="Project.Core.Pages.ObjectPage"
         Title="Object">
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Padding="5,5,5,5">
            <Label Text="{Binding SubTitle}" FontSize="21" VerticalOptions="End"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectItems}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedListItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame HasShadow="True" Margin="10">
                                <StackLayout Margin="8">
                                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

**ObjectPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Project.Core.Pages
{
    public partial class ObjectPage
    {
        public ObjectPage (ObjectItem obj)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            BindingContext = new ObjectViewModel(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

**ObjectViewModel**

```
namespace Project.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class ObjectViewModel : ObjectItemViewModel
    {

        public ObjectViewModel(ObjectItem obj) : base(obj)
        {
        }

        public override void ShowItem()
        {
                ShowViewModel<ObjectViewModel, ObjectItem>(Obj);
        }
    }
}
```

To explain more: each Object has a list of ObjectItems. And each ObjectItem has also a list of ObjectItems.
Object inherits from ObjectItem.
Here is an example:

```
Objects = new List<Object>
            {
                new Object
                {
                    Title = "Title",
                    SubTitle="subtitle",
                    ObjectItems = new List<ObjectItem>
                    {
                        new ObjectItem{Title = "title goes here" },
                        new ObjectItem{Title = "another objectItem title"},
                    }
                }
             }
```

To load these items, I created a class viewmodel, from where ObjectViewModel inherits

**ObjectItemViewModel.cs**

```
 namespace Project.Core.ViewModels
{
    public class ObjectItemViewModel : MvxViewModel<ObjectItem>
{
    public string Title => (this.Obj == null ? "/!\\ Titre" : this.Obj.Title);
    public string SubTitle => (this.Obj == null ? "/!\\ Sous Titre" : this.Obj.SubTitle);
    private List<ObjectItemViewModel> _ObjectItems;
    public List<ObjectItemViewModel> ObjectItems
        {
            get => _ObjectItems;

            set
            {
                _ObjectItems = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ObjectItems);
            }
        }
        private ObjectItem _Obj;
        public ObjectItem Obj
        {
            get => _Obj;
            set
            {
                _Obj= value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Obj);
            }
        }
        public ObjectItemViewModel _selectedListItem;
        public ObjectItemViewModel SelectedListItem
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedListItem;
            }
            set
            {
                if (SetProperty(ref _selectedListItem, value))
                    OnSelectedChangedCommand.Execute(value);
            }
        }

        public ObjectItemViewModel(ObjectItem obj)
        {
            this.Obj = obj;
            loadItems();
        }

        private MvxCommand<ObjectItemViewModel> _onSelectedChangedCommand;

        private ICommand OnSelectedChangedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _onSelectedChangedCommand ?? (_onSelectedChangedCommand = new MvxCommand<ObjectItemViewModel>((item) =>
                {
                    if (item == null)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Item null");

                        return;
                    }
                    item.ShowItem();
                }));
            }
        }


        public virtual void ShowItem()
        {
            //DO nothing


        }

        public void loadItems()
        {
            if (this.Obj != null &&
                this.Obj.ObjectItems != null &&
                this.Obj.ObjectItems.Count > 0)
            {
                ObjectItems = new List<ObjectItemViewModel>();
                foreach (ObjectItem objectItem in this.Obj.ObjectItems)
                {
                    if (objectItem.MemoItems != null && objectItem.ObjectItems.Count == 1)
                    {
                        ObjectItems.Add(new InfoViewModel(objectItem));
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        ObjectItems.Add(new ObjectViewModel(objectItem));
                        Debug.WriteLine("Item crée" + objectItem.Title);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        public override Task Initialize(ObjectItem parameter)
        {
            Obj = parameter;
            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a performance observation - you have a lot of unnecessary nested stack layouts on your page. At the root of the page there is one inside another, and there is one wrapping the list view. Have a look at the Reduce the Visual Tree Size section on this page https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/deployment-testing/performance/

Answer (score 3):

Everything you put in the ctor of a ViewModel, MvvmCross treats as something it needs to get via Dependency Injection. So in your case, since `ObjectItem` isn't registered in the MvvmCross IoC container, `ShowViewModel` cannot resolve and put into the constructor.

How this is usually solved, is to use the `Init` method in your `ViewModel` instead to pass along an object as a parameter in the `ShowViewModel` call.

If you use MvvmCross 5.x or newer this has moved into `Initialize`, when using the new `NavigationService`, but basics are more or less the same.

I think the quickest way around this in your case, is to add an empty constructor to your `ObjectViewModel`. Then add a `Init` method, in which you assign your `Obj` prop and call `loadItems()` similar to the non-empty ctor. So something like:

```
public class ObjectItemViewModel : MvxViewModel<ObjectItem>
{
    public ObjectItemViewModel() { }

    public void Init(ObjectItem obj)
    {
        Obj = obj;
        loadItems();
    }

    // rest of code
}
```

Remove the ctor from `ObjectItemViewModel`, then make `ObjectViewModel` this:

```
public class ObjectViewModel : ObjectItemViewModel
{
    public override void ShowItem()
    {
        ShowViewModel<ObjectViewModel, ObjectItem>(Obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't that what Initialize is there for?

Comment: I already implemented Initialize (look at the end of ObjectItemViewModel). I really don't understand what you wrote... Which constructor you suggest to delete?

Comment: Initialize is only called if you use NavigationService, you are not using that here, hence it won't get called. You just need to add an empty ctor and the Init method... How is that not clear?

Comment: I used ShowViewModel because there was an open issue in NAvigationService.Navigate().. What do you suggest to fix my code?

Comment: I am using MVVMCross 5.0.6 so Initialize should be working

Comment: Start by adding that empty ctor I suggested.